How can I detect the bottom of SwiftUI List?
I am trying to detect when user scrolls to bottom of the List. I have adapted this excellent solution answered here but this works only when there is a VStack inside a List. In my case, I have simple ForEach inside the List and it doesn't work as expected. It just renders Color to all of the objects in the List. Here is the my full code:
 let spaceName = "scroll"
 @State var wholeSize: CGSize = .zero
 @State var scrollViewSize: CGSize = .zero
 @Query var messages: [Message]

 var body: some View {
      ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
         ChildSizeReader($wholeSize) {
            List {
               ChildSizeReader($scrollViewSize) {
                 // VStack {  /* if I put VStack here then it somehow works, but disables other 
                 // functionalities of scrollview reader, especially when I try to scroll. (scrollView.scrollTo(message.id)*/
                  ForEach(messages.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                     if index < messages.count {
                        let message = messages[index]
                        messageView(for: message, at: index)
                           .id(message.id)
                     }
                  }
                  .background(
                     GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear.preference(
                           key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                           value: -1 * proxy.frame(in: .named(spaceName)).origin.y + 97.7 // I think this is the navigation bar height (hardcoded for now)
                        )
                     }
                  )
                  .onPreferenceChange(
                     ViewOffsetKey.self,
                     perform: { value in
                        print("offset: \(value) | content height: \(scrollViewSize.height) | whole height: \(wholeSize.height)")
                        let threshold = scrollViewSize.height - wholeSize.height
                        if value >= threshold {
                           print("User has reached the bottom of the ScrollView.")
                        } else {
                           print("not reached | Threshold: \(threshold)")
                        }
                     }
                  )
               }
            }
            .coordinateSpace(name: spaceName)
         }
      }
  }

struct ViewOffsetKey: PreferenceKey {
     typealias Value = CGFloat
     static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
     static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
       value += nextValue()
     }
}

struct ChildSizeReader<Content: View>: View {
   @Binding var size: CGSize
   
   let content: () -> Content
   var body: some View {
      // Remove ZStack from the existing answer.
      content().background(
         GeometryReader { proxy in
            Color.clear.preference(
               key: SizePreferenceKey.self,
               value: proxy.size
            )
         }
      )
      .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
         self.size = preferences
      }
    }
 }

I don't know what else to try instead of VStack, anyone who can think of the solution, would be very helpful. Thanks.

What’s wrong with this answer?

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(0..<100, id: \.self) { idx in
            if idx == 99 {
                Text("Last row")
                    .onAppear {
                        print("Hit the bottom")
                    }
            } else {
                Text("\(idx)")
            }
        }
    }
}

}
